# python float object can not be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

there is data is store in a data frame and i use the fallowing code for result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json


Data1 = 'Data/lab_202210181540.csv'


############### For Data 1 ####################
data_frame = pd.read_csv(Data1)
data_frame['data'] = data_frame['data'].apply(json.loads)
data_frame = data_frame.rename(columns={'id': 'Sr#'})
data_frame = data_frame.join(pd.json_normalize(data_frame['data']))
select_data = data_frame[['serializer']]
select_data['serializer'] = select_data['serializer'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x) if pd.notnull(x) else np.nan)
final_select_data = select_data.join(pd.json_normalize(select_data.pop('serializer')))
result = final_select_data['Analyte_line']
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
for i in range(len(df['Analyte_line'])):
    for arr in range(df['Analyte_line'][i]):
        if arr[0] in ['Urea', 'Rapid Malaria']:
            df[arr[0]][i] = "".join(map(lambda x: str(x), arr[1:]))
```

but there is error show which i unable to remove .

```
    for arr in range(df['Analyte_line'][i]):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

how to remove this error. my expecting result look like this table as a simple.

| Patient_ID | Urea | Creatinine | Uric Acid | SGOT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KYN059AQP | 3.0,3 | 3.0,3 | 3.0,3 | - |
| KQT767JLU | - | - | - | 6.0 |

The data which store in my data frame like this.

```
the fallowing data is just an example
Patient_ID,Analyte_line
KYN059AQP,"[['Urea', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Creatinine', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Uric Acid', 3.0, '3', '']]"
    KQT767JLU,"[['Total Protein', '', '6', ''], ['Albumin', '', '6', ''], ['Globulin', '', '4', ''], ['Total Bilirubin', '', '6', ''], ['Direct Bilirubin', '', '4', ''], ['Indirect Bilirubin', '', '4', ''], ['Alkaline Phosphatase', '', '4', ''], ['SGPT', '', '5', ''], ['SGOT', '', '5', ''], ['Gamma GT', '', '5', ''], ['AG Ratio', '', '4', '']]"
PWV009AGQ,"[['HGB', '', '18', ''], ['RBC', '', '1', ''], ['HCT', '', '2', ''], ['MCV', '', '3', ''], ['MCH', '', '3', ''], ['MCHC', '', '3', ''], ['RDWcv', '', '2', ''], ['RDWsd', '', '3', ''], ['WBC', '', '4', ''], ['NEU', '', '5', ''], ['LYM', '', '6', ''], ['MON', '', '', ''], ['BAS', '', '', ''], ['EO', '', '', ''], ['NEU%', '', '', ''], ['LYM%', '', '', ''], ['MON%', '', '', ''], ['EO%', '', '', ''], ['BAS%', '', '', ''], ['PLT', '', '170', ''], ['PCT', '', '3', ''], ['MPV', '', '', ''], ['PDWsd', '', '', ''], ['PDWcv', '', '', ''], ['ESR', '', '5', ''], ['GRA#', '', '', '']]"
PWV009AGQ,"[['Total Protein', '', '23', ''], ['Albumin', '', '2', ''], ['Globulin', '', '2', ''], ['Total Bilirubin', '', '2', ''], ['Direct Bilirubin', 2.0, '', ''], ['Indirect Bilirubin', 2.0, '', ''], ['Alkaline Phosphatase', '', '3', ''], ['SGPT', 1.0, '', ''], ['SGOT', '', '4', ''], ['Gamma GT', 33.0, '31', ''], ['AG Ratio', '', '2', '']]"
```

Comment: The `range` function requires an `integer` as the boundary limit. If you will pass `float` then it will throw an error. Basically, you need to convert `float` to `int` and then use it in `range`. WHY? Because numbers are continuous in nature if you give float what will be executed < layman explanation.

Comment: for i in range(len(df['Analyte_line'].fillna(0).astype(int))): ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "[['Urea', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Creatinine', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Uric Acid', 3.0, '3', '']]"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for arr in range(int(df.fillna(0)['Analyte_line'][i])):
```

This should convert the float value to int before passing into range().

Comment: for arr in range(int(df['Analyte_line'][i])):
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: I also used .isnull()

Comment: then u should use .fillna(0) before accessing the element as my edited answer

Comment: both are not working

Comment: the syntax of the statement is fine, but u have to cleanse the data before, eg. removing Nan, blank string, non numeric, making sure the index of dataframe is unique

Comment: I am afraid that there are still other bugs in your code, for example: for arr in range... => arr is an integer, arr[0] definitely raise an error.

if you want to iterate through rows, use dataframe.iterrows() instead. range(interger) will yield a list-liked object contains integers only